# Datatables Search\Filter Value in Column

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I've created a custom dropdown to filter values in a specific Datatables column. When i try to filter\search the column with the selected value, the datatable remains the same.

DataTable and Filter Event:

```
var table = $('#dt');
var dt = table.DataTable({
    ajax: {
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: '/DataTablesHandler'
    },
    columns: [
        {
            data: 'idLevel',
            orderable: false,
            targets: 'no-sort',
            searchable: true
        },
        { data: 'email' },
        { data: 'phone' },
        { data: 'fax' }
    ],
    order: [0, 'asc'],
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    orderMulti: false,
    bStateSave: true
});

//filter search on entity level change
$('#workEntityLevel').on('change', function ()
{
    var levelID = $(this).val();

    if (levelID == 0)
    {
        //clear search
        dt.search('').columns().search('').draw();
    }
    else
    {
        //search idLevel column (NOT WORKING!!!)    
        dt.columns(0).search(levelID).draw();
    }
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: is the data in the data object for that column (level id) an integer or a string?

Comment: `.val()` always returns a `string value.`

Comment: @bindrid its a number value (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6). but i've already tested it forcing a string value and the results are the same.

Comment: @Ricky it will be easier to help you If you will create a fiddle.

Comment: I tested your code, as far as I could with a table I had set up.  It worked without issue.  So, I am wondering if the "cache:false" and your ajax setup is causing the dt to expect the search to be applied server side.   I would check to see if the ajax call is being fired every time you change the drop down.

Comment: If your datasource is serverside, then you will have to handle the searching there - ie in your query.

Comment: @bindrid you're right, the filter is causing a call to the webserver (should have tested this earlier, rookie mistake...). nonetheless, my idea is to search only for the initially loaded data. is this possible?

Comment: @markpsmith that's correct. is it possible to search/filter the data that was initially loaded without requesting the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this where the ajax is separate (I did not test this but you get the idea).

```
    var tableDefinition = {

        columns: [
            {
                data: 'idLevel',
                orderable: false,
                targets: 'no-sort',
                searchable: true
            },
            { data: 'email' },
            { data: 'phone' },
            { data: 'fax' }
        ],
        order: [0, 'asc'],
        processing: true,
        serverSide: false,
        orderMulti: false,
        bStateSave: true
    };

    $(function($) {

        table = null;
        $.ajax({url: '/DataTablesHandler',
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            // if you know what the initial parameters are 
            // create an object that emulates it here.
            data : function() {JSON.stringify( { 'draw': 1, 'start': 0,
                      length:15 })},

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                // fine tune your data. Mine comes back from a web service so this code fragment reflects that.
                var parsedData = JSON.parse( data.d);
                tableDefinition.data = parsedData;

                var table = $('#dt');
                var dt = table.DataTable(tableDefinition);
            },
            error: function(a,b,c) { debugger;}
        });

        //filter search on entity level change
        $('#workEntityLevel').on('change', function ()
        {
            var levelID = $(this).val();

            if (levelID == 0)
            {
                //clear search
                dt.search('').columns().search('').draw();
            }
            else
            {
                //search idLevel column (NOT WORKING!!!)    
                dt.columns(0).search(levelID).draw();
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: i'm trying your solution, but my DataTablesHandler action needs the Datatables default parameters to query and return the data: public JsonResult DataTablesHandler(DTParameters param) {}; how can i send this data using your example?

Comment: I added a section to create the parameters object. It should be set up to look like what the server expects.

Comment: updated the example, but the parameter object continues null in the server side

Comment: what does your service side look like?

Comment: i've finally managed to upload the parameters object (needed to include adicional data to each column). when the return data is parsed i get the following error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>). a print of the returned object and the error: http://imgur.com/a/tZHiS

Comment: it's working! :D there was no need to parse the return object: tableDefinition.data = data.data; the filter doesn't trigger the ajax call, which is what i wanted. thx for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that incorporates the levelid into the search on the ajax call so you can use it to filter server side

```
    var table = $('#dt');
    var dt = table.DataTable({
        ajax: {
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: function (search) {
                // fine tune what you need to send back here.
                search.levelID = $('#workEntityLevel').val();
                return JSON.stringify(search)},
            dataType:"json",
            url: '/DataTablesHandler'
        },
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'idLevel',
                orderable: false,
                targets: 'no-sort',
                searchable: true
            },
            { data: 'email' },
            { data: 'phone' },
            { data: 'fax' }
        ],
        order: [0, 'asc'],
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        orderMulti: false,
        bStateSave: true
    });

    //filter search on entity level change
    $('#workEntityLevel').on('change', function ()
    {
        dt.draw();
    });
```

Comment: from what I read, the dt.draw() will trigger the ajax call in which I am passing back the level id

Comment: tested this version and it always triggers the ajax call. guess there is no workaround, right?